# Perforce P4Python API Bug

Tags: c++, python, perforce

I am compiling on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. The Perforce Python API uses their C++ API for some of it. So, I point the setup.py at the C++'s API directory using the --apidir= they say to use. When it starts to compile the C++, I get a whole load of errors (temporary error list link is now gone). No one else has had these errors as far as I can tell. So, my question is, is it my idiocy, or Perforce's?

P.S. The reason I don't have the flag in the command is because I setup the setup.cfg file to point at the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops! Forgot I still needed to install python-dev...